# Tools to create a 'GitHub' style index page for files/folder on a fileserver?

Tags: macos, filesystems, file-management, shell-script, github

My workplace doesn't have a document management system.
People just throw files on a shared fileserver, where search doesn't really work.

Trying to find information/files for a particular project by looking into random folders doesn't really work. There aren't any file naming conventions, and my workmates are non-tech.

My idea was to use a script/app that would traverse a given folder and create a webpage listing all the files/folders within with a description. Adding the description would require editing the html file directly, but other meta data (file size, creation date etc) would just be automatically read from the filesystem. It would also pickup a README.MD file if present that describes the folder/project and append that to the page. Very similar to how GitHub project page works/looks.

I accept that it may need to be re-run periodically to ensure the listing is correct as contents of the folder are updated.The fileserver appears to be a standard windows fileshare, I access it using SMB from my mac. I have no admin access to the fileserver, and it's admin is done offshore by an IT help desk. I won't be able to get them to run any services or processes on the fileserver.

My thoughts are just to generate a 'index.html' file for each project folder root and tell coworkers to just open that file to learn about a project.

Any ideas on if such a tool exists?

I'm a mac user, the rest are mostly windows. I'd be the main/only user of this software though.

See example of GitHub page [here](https://github.com/al3x/sovereign).

Comment: Where would the description come from?

Comment: Can you provide some details on fileserver's setup? Can you run HTTP server on it?

Comment: I don't have any access to the fileserver, cannot change/add software or services. I can't add Sharepoint etc to it. I can only run a script/app on my client to 'document' existing folders when I mount the fileshare or create new project folders on it.

Answer (score 0):

Apache, provides a mod_autoindex that is pretty configurable.

Take a look in https://github.com/ramlmn/Apache-Directory-Listing